# Webpacker gem `resolved_paths` "not found or unreadable" error when importing a scss file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

### Background

- Rails: 5.1.4
- Gems:

  - webpacker: 3.0.1
- Packages:

  - @rails/webpacker: 3.0.2
  - vue: 2.5.2
  - vue-loader: 13.3.0
  - vue-template-compiler: 2.5.2
- "Fairly new to JS development; i.e. webpack"

### Problem

Everything already works, but only except now that I try to import a scss file that resides in the `app/assets/stylesheets/imports/_variables.scss` instead of the current file's relative path; giving me an error in Chrome console:

[image]

Here's the line where I try to import it:

**app/javascript/games/cards/Card.vue**

```
<template>
...
</template>

<script>
...
</script>

<style lang='scss' scoped>
@import 'stylesheets/imports/variables';
...
</style>
```

I read the [webpacker doc](https://github.com/rails/webpacker#resolved), and hence I updated my **config/webpacker.yml** `resolved_paths`, restarted my `rails server` but still fails.

**config/webpacker.yml**

```
# Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: ['app/assets']

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  extensions:
    - .coffee
    - .erb
    - .js
    - .jsx
    - .ts
    - .vue
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  dev_server:
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    hmr: false
    https: false
...
```

*P.S. I am running `rails server` without running `bin/webpack-dev-server`, but error persists when running also `bin/webpack-dev-server`*

I'd be grateful to any help or any possible debugging process.